# How do I use a HTML data-attribute in SCSS?

Tags: html, sass

I was looking for a simple way to implement dark/light mode on my site and have settled on this method as of right now:

Setting a data attribute on the body that contains the current theme

```
<body name="body" theme="dark">
```

A JavaScript function to swap between the themes:

```js
let themeToggle = document.getElementById("theme-toggle")
let body = document.getElementsByName("body").item(0)
let currentTheme = body.getAttribute("theme")

function toggleTheme() {
    currentTheme = (currentTheme == "dark") ? "light" : "dark"
    body.setAttribute("theme", currentTheme)
}
```

---

With the current approach I am currently splitting my CSS into multiple CSS/SCSS files, a layout one (`syle.scss`), a `dark.scss`, a `light.scss` and a `_colors.scss`.

However, with this I end up with two very similar SCSS files like this:

`dark.scss:`

```scss
@use 'colors' as c;

body[theme="dark"] {
    background-color: c.$dark-background;

    #theme-toggle {
        border-color: c.$light-background;
    }

    div {
        background-color: c.$dark-accent;
    }
}
```

`light.scss:`

```scss
@use 'colors' as c;

body[theme="light"] {
    background-color: c.$light-background;

    #theme-toggle {
        border-color: c.$dark-background;
    }

    div {
        background-color: c.$light-accent;
    }
}
```

---

Now I am wondering if there was a possibility to do something like this:

```scss
body {
    $activeTheme: attr(theme);
    @if $activeTheme == "dark" {
        $inactiveTheme: "light";
    } @else {
        $inactiveTheme: "dark";
    }

    background-color: c.{$activeTheme}-background;

    #theme-toggle {
        border-color: c.{$inactiveTheme}-background;
    }

    div {
        background-color: c.{$activeTheme}-accent;
    }
}
```

I have tried to use interpolation, but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use Sass in this way. Sass is compiled to CSS before it is sent client-side, so by the time it's in a user's browser alongside the HTML and JS, Sass variables don't exist anymore and any interpolation has already happened.

Consider swapping stylesheets based on the theme mode, or using regular CSS variables.